# I get syntax error on my print statement in my function. I don't know what I am doing wrong

Tags: python, syntax-error

This code works in terminal but not atom. I get a syntax error on the return print line. Sorry if it is obvious, I am new to programming.

```
#returns footage stretched


material_feet = input('Material Feet: ')
material_inches = input('Material Inches: ')
actual_feet = input('Actual Feet: ')
actual_inches = input('Actual Inches: ')

def Stretch(material_feet, material_inches, actual_feet, actual_inches):
    material_total = material_feet * 12 + material_inches
    actual_total = actual_feet * 12 + actual_inches

    amount_stretched = (actual_total - material_total) * 12 / actual_total
    difference = divmod((actual_total - material_total), 12)
    return print('Material stretched total of ' + str(difference) + ' and stretched ' + str(amount_stretched) + ' per foot.')

Stretch(int(material_feet), int(material_inches), int(actual_feet), int(actual_inches))
```

Comment: please add proper error and check python version in both terminal and in atom.

Comment: print() returns None so you should not return print just omit the return statement

Comment: `return print(...)` is valid code Python 3, but invalid in Python 2.

Answer (score 0):

The `print` statement simply outputs whatever is inside it to `stdout`, but it still returns a `None` value. Try doing `x = print('Hello world!')` in a terminal. You'll see that while `Hello world!` is printed in terminal, the value of `x` is still `None`.

So your code is the same as just using `print` without returning anything. I'm not sure why Atom is pointing that out as a syntax error, but it's certainly not conventional to do it.

Answer (score 0):

**return** leaves the current function call with the **expression list (or None)** as the return value.
So you can't use print in the return statement instead of that, you can use like the below code.

```
def Stretch(material_feet, material_inches, actual_feet, actual_inches):
    return str(difference),str(amount_stretched)
diff , amt_str = Stretch(int(material_feet), int(material_inches), int(actual_feet), int(actual_inches))
```

Or you can able to return as list / tuple/dict:

```
def Stretch(material_feet, material_inches, actual_feet, actual_inches):
        return [str(difference),str(amount_stretched)]
    LIST = Stretch(int(material_feet), int(material_inches), int(actual_feet), int(actual_inches))
```

Comment: sure you can use `print`, in Python 3, but not in Python 2, where it is a statement

Answer (score 0):

The answer is given by @VPfB in the comments on the question itself.  `print` is a function in Python 3...it returns a value, and so `return print("foo")` is a valid statement.  But in Python 2, print is a statement but not a function...it does not return a value.  Trying to treat it like it does, like as in `return print("foo")`, leads to a syntax error from the interpreter.

This is why @JaydeepDevda asks the OP which version of Python he is running.  I think it's very likely he's running Python 3 at the terminal, but Python 2 in Atom.  This would explain the difference in behavior.